# angular not display the array of objects received from the http respnse

Tags: angular, http

its returned 304 instead 200 and the array undefined

i were short the code just for the main.

> app.modules.ts:

```
import { EmployeesModule } from './modules/employees/employees.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


  imports: [
    EmployeesModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ]};
```

> employees.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

export class EmployeesService {
  employeesUrl: string = "http://localhost:3333/Employees";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getEmployeesData(): Observable<IEmployee[]> {
    return this.http
    .get<IEmployee[]>(this.employeesUrl);
  }
```

> employees-layout.component.ts

```
  constructor(private employeesService: EmployeesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEmployees();
  }

  getEmployees(): void {
    this.employeesService.getEmployeesData()
    .subscribe(employees => this.allEmployees = employees);
  }

}
```

it does not load the array and it's not empty and the data that returned its undefined.
I tried to change the syntax many times but it doesn't work

Comment: Check your backend server your angular code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the message you get is 302, it means the code is probably ok, but the URL you call has some issues.

Error 302 can mean a [lot of things](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/302-found). What is the backend API you are calling? Your wrote `http://localhost:3333/Employees` is there any server on the same machine where you test the application(localhost means the same host you run your browser)? Does this same error happen if you try to call a [different test api on the web](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)?

Comment: I was tried to fill data in JSON by using this URL and its working but when I try to take the data from there and put it in an array it not responded well. this is my server:https://github.com/typicode/json-server.